# How to write curry and compose in Typescript 4?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, composition, currying

After going through [variadic types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types) I wanted to make this, but I'm wondering how to use array of functions.

This is my first try:

```js
function curry<T extends any[]>(fn: (...args: T) => any) {
  return function(...args: T) {
    return args.length >= fn.length
      ? fn(...args)
      : curry(fn.bind(undefined, ...args));
  }
}
```

But for `fn.bind` I'm getting "The 'this' context of type '(...args: T) => any' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(this: undefined, ...args: any[]) => any'."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not really using [variadic tuple tpes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) in your code.  The specific flavor of `curry()` you're implementing is one that takes a partial parameter list and then possibly returns another function that takes a partial remainder of the list.  That means the initial tuple of parameters `T` might be split into many different pieces, and this is therefore not going to be automatically inferred from context the way that the `partialCall()` function in the documentation can.

Instead, you need to explicitly break the `T` tuples apart into possible subtuples.  Let's represent the type of the desired output of `curry()` that takes a function whose parameters are the tuple `A` and whose return type is `R`:

```
type Curried<A extends any[], R> =
  <P extends Partial<A>>(...args: P) => P extends A ? R :
    A extends [...SameLength<P>, ...infer S] ? S extends any[] ? Curried<S, R>
    : never : never;

type SameLength<T extends any[]> = Extract<{ [K in keyof T]: any }, any[]>
```

Let me translate that into English. A `Curried<A, R>` is a generic function, whose arguments must be of some tuple type `P` that is constrained to `Partial<A>`.

For tuples, `Partial<A>` ends up meaning that you can leave out any suffix of the tuple (from some place to the end).  So `[1, 2, 3]` is assignable to `Partial<[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]>`, but `[1, 2, 4]` is not.  There's a bit of a wrinkle with `undefined`, since `[1, undefined, 3]` is also assignable to `Partial<[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]>`, but I'm going to ignore that and if it becomes important it can be worked around.  Anyway, it means that the arguments to `Curried<A, R>` must be some prefix (initial chunk) of the `A` tuple.

The return type of `Curried<A, R>` depends on the prefix `P` passed in.  If `P` is the whole tuple `A`, then the return type is just `R` (that's what happens when you've finally given the function all its arguments).  Otherwise, you split `A` into the prefix `P` and its suffix `S`, and return a new curried function of type `Curried<S, R>`.

Splitting `A` into `[...SameLength<P>, ...infer S]` uses variadic tuple types.  Note that `SameLength<P>` is just a tuple the same length as `P` but with its element types as `any`.  This avoids a problem where `P` is inferred to be very narrow (say `A` is `[number, number, number]` and then `P` is `[0, 0]`.  You can't split `[number, number, string]` into `[0, 0, ...infer S]` because `number` isn't assignable to `0`.  But all we care about is length here, so we split `[number, number, string]` into `[any, any, ...infer S]` and that works, and infers `S` to be `string`).

Okay, use and implement it:

```
function curry<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R): Curried<A, R> {
  return (...args: any[]): any =>
    args.length >= fn.length ? fn(...args as any) : curry((fn as any).bind(undefined, ...args));
}
```

I used a whole lot of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) inside the implementation of `curry()`, because the compiler is almost hopelessly lost at trying to verify that the returned function will be assignable to `Curried<A, R>`.  Instead of worrying about it, I just tell the compiler not to bother verifying safety, and take responsibility myself for making the implementation correct.  (If it's wrong, I blame myself, not the compiler).

Okay, so there we go.  Does it work?

```
const fn = (a: string, b: number, c: boolean) => (a.length <= b) === c ? "yep" : "nope";

const cFn = curry(fn);
const val1 = cFn("")(1)(true);
console.log(val1); // yep

const val2 = cFn("", 1, true);
console.log(val2); // yep

const val3 = cFn()()()()("", 1)()()(true); // yep
```

Looks good to me.  Note that according to my definition if you call a `Curried<A, R>` with no arguments you just get back a `Curried<A, R>`.  Here are some intentional errors so you can see that the compiler catches them:

```
// errors
cFn(1, 1, true); // error!
//  ~ <-- not a string
cFn("", 1, true, false); // error!
//               ~~~~~ <-- Expected 0-3 arguments, but got 4
cFn("")(1)(false)(true); // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- This expression is not callable.
```

These look like the correct errors to me.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygQwLZQDJQHYHMQAsA8AKjFAB4iYAmAzjAhmANoC6AfDALwwCi5ATggDGIfAG8YjANIwAlhhgBrKGAD2AMxiFmALjoMYAXwA0epm2ChIsAMIBXPnxlRK+AIIlyVWvTMmASuxcwDAw+AAKHhQYNDBhCHwgMggANm6srAAUAHQ58VjUumEAlJzsEWRRMe4A-DB+MNrBITDuFV4SOVmIKOjYeOGsJp1yalB88MwwtXCR7T4sUzB2Dk4ucP6sTSG6GFAAbmMNMLsHfADcFmq2GMIyKvKC9nxgbrPR3gwsGxlqGLrZuT4+V0rhKHHYfiKumWjmcbg2MFETT4UBA9nkAKyeQKphYUNMpS2dCB1CyyUwOFwMFYXF+ZIpeEWv0x2LoHzAJV0jwcYAyP3kCHZRSyACM5JQMtdKFA1HJnENAfkikULgYLIJ7tQQDBfpwYBkELotY5sCYRTtbEgRWMTIJdCKVCpyfQwewDfS+lT8FwRWCOFxBIsAERgKAQINHIMYFTQIMXYAajBamCCABi8gDT15vxVCc12r2KQAjHq0xgMkGg0UMkXqyA+LYoLnE9QnVAySosBlC8la2cYAB6AcwUMQdX5mA9gBMpfTFaDJiLJnrjebmrbHa705Vg+Ho-HSYLKQAzLPy9WLxlq5XF5e6w2m-2hyOwxZn2M+Co+NQE3OlzB-xXR9dxIBwvwAQmAZ8YAAP1CABaeDjhUbUEBgY05CwX9yxvADlwfEw1BSahgPfMC+Eg6DmmomjYJg+i4PwRCeFIaBhGcGAAAZ4NPPJLUwEBqDNWxtSwFCYAAFmw+dq1rH5iKbDIgJ3MjPwoqCBwYrTtIYhCkMIXAZFoMgIBRahqDueQjOQ7VBBSZIEBFcksmAIA)

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much - it would take me only a decade to write this. Also seems I didn't quite get variadic types completely on first look.

Comment: This implementation does not work for generic functions, all generic parameters get promoted to ``any``. Is this a typescript limitation?

Comment: Yeah, TypeScript lacks support for "higher kinded types" (see [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) for the feature requests) outside of a few specific scenarios (like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions)) so there's little chance of propagating type parameters automatically in something like `Curried`.